# How do I bundle a specific webkit build with my Cocoa App

Tags: javascript, cocoa, xcode, webkit

I've got a Hybrid Cocoa/Webkit application that has extensive Javascript usage, and seems to break every time Apple updates the Safari browser (or the underlying webkit framework in OSX).  I understand it will probably mean a much bigger binary, but is there a way to force my application to use an older, bundled WebKit framework vs. the one that is available in the System Libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is impossible / impractical to do.  Even if you are able to successfully bundle WebKit with an application, it will behave strangely or crash when interacting with other applications, for instance, copy and pasting from Mail (which uses native webkit) to your app (which would be using a different bundled version of WebKit) can cause versioning issues and crashes.